# PHP SQL Return just returns "Array"

Tags: firebird, php4

I've tried using something similar to the following PHP code to retrieve items from a Firebird database.

```
$sql = "select P_1,P_2,P_3 from p_players('$playerid', '')";
//This sends the SQL select statement to the db
$rs=$db->Execute($sql);
//This converts the SQL statement to an array
$result = $rs->GetArray();
echo $result;
```

However, the echo result that I receive keeps returning "Array" no matter what I select as the database to query. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Switch your `echo` to a `var_dump` or `print_r`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$sql = "select P_1,P_2,P_3 from p_players('$playerid', '')";
//This sends the SQL select statement to the db
$rs=$db->Execute($sql);
//This converts the SQL statement to an array
$result = $rs->GetArray();
print_r $result;
```